# Elastic Beanstalk - Denying access to directory/subdirectory (Nginx)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**My environment:** 
Platform: PHP 8.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.12 
Proxy server: Nginx

**What I need:** 

To deny access to the `/img` directory and its files.

**What I've tried:**

1.Creating this folder in the root of my source code: `.ebextensions`

2.Adding a `newconf.config` file with the following content into the folder above:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_conf.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           location /img {
               return 403;
           }
```

3.Upload & deploy in Elastic Beanstalk.

**Outcome:**
There's no error message but I'm still able to access the `/img` directory because `my_conf.conf` isn't created in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

**Remarks:**
I'm open other solutions that will help block access to the `/img` directory.

**Solution:**
So Marcin was partly right about the path but it was crucial in helping me find the solution.

If you place it in  `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, you might get this error during deployment: `"location" directive is not allowed here`

So here's what needs to be done:

1.Create a directory of `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/` in your source code.

2.Create a conf file and put your configs in it. In my case I'm using `my_conf.conf` :

```
location /img {
    return 404;
}
```

3.Upload & deploy.

That's it. I got the solution [here](https://mseeeen.msen.jp/elastic-beanstalk-php-nginx-conf/). Do note the link is in Japanese and I had to use a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using  `64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.12`. Thus your nginx settings should be located in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` (not `.ebextensions`) as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

You can try with `.platform/nginx/conf.d/my_conf.conf` with the content of:

```
location /img {
     return 403;
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering. I'm now able to put the file into Elastic Beanstalk but the config isn't working. I'm still able to access the contents of the directory. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @Jenga Must be nginx issue. Probably your configuration is incorrect. I just addressed the problem of why your files don't get created.

Comment: No worries, I've just found the solution. Cheers!